# How to: Find and update all the entries where the value in one column shows up more than once

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns:

- subid - id of the resource
- authorid - id of the author
- ordering - order of author within citation

For an application where users can submit resources and cite multiple authors. Authors can cite primary and secondary authors in their submissions and usually do.

There is one case where a user (call him user 111) submitted all entries listing himself as the primary and the actual author as secondary. Unfortunately that person has left the project so it has fallen to me to fix this (I have to do it purely in sql).

I am trying to figure out how to build a query to do the following:

- Find all entries
- where the subid value shows up more than once in the table
- where at least one of the authorid values is 111
- where the ordering for 111 is greater than the ordering for any users that are not 111
  & update them so
- the not(111) author has ordering of '0'
- and the 111 author has ordering '1'

Comment: 2. Possible ordering values = {0,1}?

Comment: "where the ordering for 111 is greater than the ordering for any users that are not 111 & update them so
the not(111) author has ordering of '0'
and the 111 author has ordering '1'" => This update will end with a 111 ordering greater than not-111 ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
UPDATE tbl a
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT subid
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY subid
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(author_id = 111) > 0
    ) b ON a.subid = b.subid
SET a.ordering = (a.author_id = 111)
```

Replace `tbl` with your actual table name.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Could you walk me through how it did? Here's my best guess: The subquery pulls just those values on tbl with multiple entries. Then you set the value of ordering in each row to ... and that's where I get confused. Thanks again for your help!